# Как сделать проверку пользовательского ввода в telegram бот'е?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите, как реализовать проверку пользовательского ввода по фото на python? Желательно с библиотекой telebot.

Покажу на примере кода:

```
def step(message): #тут наверное что-то другое будет
    try:
        if #пользователь ввёл текст
           pass
        if #пользователь ввёл цифры
           pass
        if #пользователь отправил картинку/фото
           pass
        if #пользователь отправил документ
           pass
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')
```

Comment: что значит проверка по фото?

Comment: @Gladius, если пользователь отправил картинку/фотографию, работает такое-то условие. 
Также интересно как проверять по типу текст/цифры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def step(message):
    if message.text.isalpha():
        print('пользователь ввёл текст')
    elif message.text.isdigit():
         print('пользователь ввёл цифры')
    else:
         print('другое')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'photo'])
def handle_docs(message):
```

- `isalpha()` для того чтобы проверить содержит ли строка (сообщение пользователя) только буквы + content_types=["text"]
- `isdigit()` для того чтобы проверить содержит ли строка (сообщение пользователя) только цифры + content_types=["text"]
- `content_types=["photo"]` пользователь отправил картинку/фото либо
  `message.content_type == 'photo'`
- `content_types=["document"]` пользователь отправил документ либо
  `message.content_type == 'document'`

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types

Comment: Спасибо большое)